# magento - add totals block in shipment email

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have a problem that can't solve all day. I want to display a totals block in shipment email after ordered items like in invoice email. (When order status is changed from administration)
Here is my code in sales.xml

```
<sales_email_order_shipment_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_shipment_items" name="items" template="email/order/shipment/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_default</block><template>email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_invoice_totals" name="invoice_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="core/text_list" name="additional.product.info" />
</sales_email_order_shipment_items>
```

in template\email\order\shipment\items.phtml I added this

```
<tfoot>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('invoice_totals'); ?>
</tfoot>
```

but nothing happend.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you disabled your system cache? You code looks like it should print the invoice totals (twice).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve this problem by myself. If anyone need to add prices to shipment email here is the way:

Open *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml* and replace all code with this one:

```
    <?php $_shipment = $this->getShipment() ?>
<?php $_order    = $this->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_shipment && $_order): ?>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="650" style="border:1px solid #EAEAEA;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Item') ?></th>
            <th align="left" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Sku') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?></th>
            <th align="center" bgcolor="#EAEAEA" style="font-size:13px; padding:3px 9px"><?php echo $this->__('Price'); ?>:</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_shipment->getAllItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) continue; else $i++; ?>
    <tbody<?php echo $i%2 ? ' bgcolor="#F6F6F6"' : '' ?>>
        <?php echo $this->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
        </tbody>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <tfoot>
        <tr class="subtotal">
            <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                Subtotal
            </td>
            <td align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                <span class="price"><?php echo $_order->formatPriceTxt($_order->getSubtotal()); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="shipping">
            <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                Delivery:
            </td>
            <td align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                <span class="price"><?php echo $_order->formatPriceTxt($_order->getShippingAmount()); ?></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="grand_total">
            <td colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                <strong>Total</strong>
            </td>
            <td align="right" style="padding:3px 9px">
                <strong><span class="price"><?php echo $_order->formatPriceTxt($_order->getSubtotal() + $_order->getShippingAmount()); ?></span></strong>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Now we are included totals, but we need to display the price for each product in tbody.

So open *app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/items/shipment/default.phtml*
And after

```
<?php $_item = $this->getItem() ?>
```

add this

```
<?php $_order = $this->getItem()->getOrder(); ?>
```

at the end of code before closing tr tag add this lines:

```
<td align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:11px; padding:3px 9px;">
<?php echo $_order->formatPrice($_item->getPrice()); ?>
```

Comment: You should copy app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/shipment/items.phtml to your local template folder. Then double check your Admin -> Config -> General -> Design -> Themes ... to make sure your Templates and Layout folder are set (or Default)